# React Select searchable dropdown blue outline

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-select

Select; when the dropdown is searchable, there is a blue  outline around the cursor:

https://ibb.co/faG4X8

I can get rid of the cursor by using this:

```
.Select-input > input {
    color: transparent;
  }
```

How can i also get rid of the blue outline on focus

thanks,

mihai

Comment: oops, i guess i found fix but if someone else has a better deep-nested fix, please post. for now, this works: .Select-input * {
    outline: 0;
  }

Answer (score -1):

You are correct that `outline: 0` or `outline: none` will remove the blue outline when an element is focused.

That is from the browser's default stylesheet. Each browser implements that focus state indicator in some way.

I would caution you to be aware that the focus indication is important for accessibility. If the default styling is removed, it's best to replace it with some other visual indicator that the element is focused. Without that change, it makes a site nigh-impossible to traverse if someone is using a keyboard, or potentially other non-traditional methods of access.

From the html5 spec--

> “…if an alternative focusing style isn’t made available instead, the page will be significantly less usable for people who primarily navigate pages using a keyboard, or those with reduced vision who use focus outlines to help them navigate the page.”

further reading: [Stop messing with the browsers default focus outline](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/28/stop-messing-with-the-browsers-default-focus-outline/)